# No content in iframe tag on localhost and local html file for flask project (in vs code on mac)

Tags: html, iframe

I have s simple index.html and within an iframe tag. But the page stays blank no matter how I write the src url. What could be the reason?
I tried:

```
<iframe src="localhost:5000/test.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:5000/test.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="test.html"></iframe>
```

test.html is in the same directory as index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have figured it out, but I still want to share my late answer here.

In your .py file, include a function like this:

```
@app.route('/frame') # the route can be whatever you want
def show_frame():
    return render_template('test.html')
```

And in the html file, change the src of  iframe tag to:

```
<iframe src="{{ url_for('show_frame') }}"></iframe>
```

This works for me.